# Tinymce echo Images next to each other instead below

Tags: php, tinymce

I have a MYSQL database where I store images for reports I can import them to the Tinymce text area but they are being placed below each other. Is there away I can make them place two two next to each other. Some reports have 2 photos and other might have 10 depending on how many was loaded to the DB

This is my current code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images WHERE file_nr = '$id'");
        ?>
           <?php
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
               echo "<div id='img_div'>";
               echo "<img width='300' height='300' display: inline-block; 
                        src='../../cases_1/overdue/images/".$row['image']."' >";
               echo "<p>".$row['image_text']."</p>";
               echo "</div>";
               }
           ?>
```

I tried inline-block not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the cleanest method but got this working

```
 <?php
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
               echo "<div id='img_div'>";
               echo "<img width='350px' height='350px' style='float: left; padding: 4px;' src='../../cases_1/overdue/images/".$row['image']."' >";
               echo "</div>";
           }
  ?>
```